# Individual options in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out how I can work variables into my sql queries.

I am using a 5 question system over 5 different forms, so a person can find a car that will suit their needs. On all of the question that are asked, they will be displayed in a dropdown box populated from the database. I need the code to be flexible because items will be added and removed. We know how many companies and model of vehicles there are.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
<select id="bodyType" name="bodyType" style="width:80%">
<option value="all">All Styles</option>
    <?php 
        $sql = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT DISTINCT `type` FROM catalogue WHERE `available` = '1' AND brand = '$query1'");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo "<option value=". $row['type'] . ">" . $row['type'] . "</option>";
        }
    ?>
```

As you can see by the code I have placed the $query1 which is the brand. The problem I am having is that if the person chooses any make, I am not sure how to show that in the SQL. I would drop the AND brand = '$query1' normally but over the 5 forms I would have to write a load of if/else statements.

I am asking:

Is there a way to have php insert or remove that part dynamically?
Is there a symbol I can use? I know the * is to find all records is there something similar that can be used in the AND section of the query?

I thank you for your time and hope I have been clear.

Greg

Comment: 5 forms or 5 fields?

Comment: Sorry I ask 5 questions on 5 different forms. I have no idea about ajax as of yet. So I have the person click the submit button and takes them to the next form on another page.

Comment: How difficult it is to change it to have 5 fields in 1 form? It would be easier. But anyway, it that's not possible, we can figure out how to solve this. **Edit:** With "difficult" I mean if your project requirement allows to change it

Comment: You have great... no! THE GIANT security problem! PLEASE replace the substring (brand = '$query1') with (brand = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $query1) . "')

Comment: Thank you v. sheldeshov I was just using a generic system but it would make good practice to put them in as working on the code. 

Carlosherrera - Yes I have tried to get that working but unsuccessfully I would rather the easier way than the long way.